# how to read two columns in XLSX into R

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to read an XLSX sheet into an R dataframe:

```
Dutch_List <- read.xlsx2("file.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, startRow = 1, colIndex=5,endRow = 10000, as.data.frame = TRUE, header=TRUE)
Dutch_Status <- read.xlsx2("File.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, startRow = 1, colIndex=8,endRow = 10000, as.data.frame = TRUE, header=TRUE)
```

Is there a way to read columns 5 and 8, without reading columns 5 through 8?
I just want the two columns...

Thanks

Comment: `colIndex = c(5,8)`. Also, `as.data.frame` is `TRUE` by default, so you don't need to include that argument if you want to save some typing. Likewise, if you want to read all rows, there's no need to include `startRow` and `endRow`.

Comment: perfect.  That's what I needed.  Please copy that comment into an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colIndex = c(5,8)`.

Also, `as.data.frame` is `TRUE` by default, so you don't need to include that argument if you want to save some typing. Likewise, if you want to read all rows, there's no need to include `startRow` and `endRow`.